# Is there an easy way to bind a command to a listbox in MVVM WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been trying to create a fairly simple application in WPF following the MVVM development pattern but I have been going crazy over how difficult it seems to be to do simple things. I have already created this app in Forms and had it successfully running, but my boss requested I rewrite the interface in WPF as a demo of the technology. I decided to try to follow as many best practices as I can in order to make the app and code as educational as possible. My current dilemma is using a listbox to run some code every time the selection changes. I'm ready to just use the code-behind with an event to call the method on the view-model. To me this seems to still be essentially MVVM since no logic is executing. Thanks for any help/insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply binding selecteditem property of listbox... on selection change a setter in the view model will be called and you can do  what ever you want...

Here is  a sample which will help you

**XAML**

```
  <Grid Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Bisque">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmploye}"/>
        </Grid>
```

**View Model**

```
public  class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<Employee> _employes;

        public List<Employee> Employes
        {
            get { return _employes; }
            set { _employees = value; OnPropertyChanged("Employes"); }
        }
        private Employee _selectedEmploye;

        public Employee SelectedEmploye
        {
            get { return _selectedEmploye; }
            set
            {
                _selectedEmployee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmploye");
            }
        }

    }
```

**View model base**

```
public  class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**Employee Class**

```
public class Employee : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This really helps to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: That's actually good. But when you are unlucky to have a nice Propriety to workaround, like `Loaded` event, you'll need some `EventToCommand` framework.

Answer (score 2):

In your ViewModel you can create a Property "SelectedItem". Bind then the SelectedItem-property if your ListBox to your property.

- If it's a POCO clr-property (INotifyPropertyChanged), then you can trigger your code from the properties setter.
- IF it's a DependencyProperty, you have to add a PropertyChangedCallback and trigger your code from there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to use code-behind. No code-behind is a guideline to avoid too much logic being placed in the view, not a hard and fast rule. In this case (as others have suggested) you can bind the SelectedItem property to some property on your viewmodel. With non-data-related events, my recommendation would be to handle the event as normal and delegate execution logic to the viewmodel.

In my opinion, design patterns should always be taken as rule of thumb and used with some judgement as it's quite easy to apply them too strictly in areas where they don't belong, which usually makes things worse.

Comment: I tend to agree with you here, but luckily it looks like there are some easier ways to do this without jumping through all the hoops I thought I would have to.

Comment: @pauleck1 - If you ever feel like you're needlessly jumping through hoops, it's probably time to take a step back and reconsider whether you're taking the right approach. With all of the MVVM frameworks out there, it's easy to hopelessly over-engineer things and make your code harder to maintain (which somewhat defeats the purpose). Not that I'm saying MVVM is bad, it's certainly my weapon of choice when working with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `EventToCommand` behavior in [Galasoft MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

[Here's the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131142/mvvm-light-silverlight-using-eventtocommand-with-a-combobox)

Comment: I'll have to check that out in some depth. I was really hoping to avoid adding another framework to the project though.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind to ListBox.SelectedItem to get the selected item in your vm.